# One of my asynctasks doesn't execute when I re-launch the activity

Tags: java, android

I have 9 asynctasks running (8 are from 1 class and 1 from another), whenever I re-launch the activity the first 8 threads run but that 1 that is different doesn't, I can't find why.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;

ImageView iv1;
ImageView iv2;
ImageView iv3;
ImageView iv4;
ImageView iv5;
ImageView iv6;
ImageView iv7;
ImageView iv8;

ImageView h1;
ImageView h2;
ImageView h3;

boolean salir;

int puntuacion;
int vidas;

Hilo hilo;
Hilo hilo2;
Hilo hilo3;
Hilo hilo4;
Hilo hilo5;
Hilo hilo6;
Hilo hilo7;
Hilo hilo8;

Ganar ganar;

int cerrar;
boolean fin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    puntuacion = 0;
    vidas = 3;
    salir = false;
    cerrar = 0;
    fin = false;

    tv = findViewById(R.id.puntuacion);

    iv1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    iv4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    iv5 = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    iv6 = findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    iv7 = findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    iv8 = findViewById(R.id.imageView8);

    h1 = findViewById(R.id.heart1);
    h2 = findViewById(R.id.heart2);
    h3 = findViewById(R.id.heart3);

    hilo = new Hilo(iv1);
    hilo2 = new Hilo(iv2);
    hilo3 = new Hilo(iv3);
    hilo4 = new Hilo(iv4);
    hilo5 = new Hilo(iv5);
    hilo6 = new Hilo(iv6);
    hilo7 = new Hilo(iv7);
    hilo8 = new Hilo(iv8);

    ganar = new Ganar();

    BlockingQueue<Runnable> mWorkQueue =
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(9);


    ThreadPoolExecutor mThreadPool =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    9,
                    9,
                    3,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    mWorkQueue
            );

    hilo.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo2.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo3.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo4.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo5.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo6.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo7.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);
    hilo8.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);

    ganar.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPool);

    iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv1, hilo);
        }
    });
    iv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv2, hilo2);
        }
    });
    iv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv3, hilo3);
        }
    });
    iv4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv4, hilo4);
        }
    });
    iv5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv5, hilo5);
        }
    });
    iv6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv6, hilo6);
        }
    });
    iv7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv7, hilo7);
        }
    });
    iv8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(iv8, hilo8);
        }
    });

}

public void updatePuntuacion() {
    tv.setText("Puntuacion: " + puntuacion);
}

public void updateVidas() {
    if(vidas==2) {
        h3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if(vidas==1) {
        h2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if(vidas==0) {
        h1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void click(ImageView iv, Hilo h) {
    if(h.isEstado()) {
        puntuacion+=10;
        updatePuntuacion();
        h.setEstado(false);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
    } else {
        vidas-=1;
        updateVidas();
    }
}

private class Hilo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public boolean isEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    ImageView img;
    boolean ganado = false;
    boolean estado;

    public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Hilo (ImageView img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        estado = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if(estado == true) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
            estado = false;
        } else {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.topo);
            estado = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        while(!salir) {
            if(fin) {
                cancel(true);
            } else if(estado == true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*5000 + 3000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                publishProgress();
            } else if(estado == false){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*500 + 3000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                publishProgress();
            } else {
                publishProgress();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}

private class Ganar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public Ganar () {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        fin = true;
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClasificacionesActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        while(!salir) {
            if(vidas < 1) {
                salir = true;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public void onBackPressed(){

    if(cerrar > 0) {
        Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(a);
    } else {
        cerrar++;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vuelve a tocar atrás para cerrar la aplicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}
```

Hilo asynctasks run whenever I relaunch the activity (when you loose the game it goes to another activity where you can go to the game again with an intent) but Ganar asynctask doesn't so you can't loose again.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can hugely simplify all this code with a couple of loops and arrays.

Comment: I know I could do it much more simple, but my teacher insisted on using asynctasks for it

Answer (score 0):

Your entire way of doing this is wrong.  You should not have a constantly running AsyncTask ever-  if you need that use a Thread.  And having a thread busy looping looking for a variable to change is NEVER the right way to do something, instead you should check as you change the variable, or even use asynchronous signaling like a semaphore or rxjava.

Finally, you can't just declare a variable and see changes between threads like that unless the variable is declared to be volatile.  Otherwise the compiler will optimize it and never actually fetch the value from memory again, it will use a locally cached version.

Comment: I know it is wrong and it's better to use threads (and I should not even use them here) but my teacher wanted us to use asynctasks for it (he said thread does not work on Android, I know it does but whatever).

This is just something too complex for us to understand (he doesn't even know why the asynctask has 3 types of how they work and why they're there), and as I say, we don't have the level to use asynctasks but he insisted on using them, that's why I have such a horrible code.